# How to find the name of the parent program that started us?

Tags: delphi

We want a program of ours in D7 to know if it was run via a ShellExecute command from one of our apps, or directly started by the user.

Is there a reliable way for a Delphi 7 program to determine the name of the program that ran it?

We of course could have our parent program use a command line argument or other flag, but we'd prefer the above approach.

TIA

Comment: Use a command line parameter. A trivial solution that works and will work forever. Don't fight it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan By far the easiest, but also easily cheated. A different solution could be to make the starting program send a message (if it is one of those 'own apps'). This method can also be fooled, be it somewhat harder. Question is, how important is this feature. Who or what would die if someone tricked the app by adding the command line argument when starting it from Start->Run or from a shortcut...

Comment: Raymond describes a more advanced method of passing data here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/11/56043.aspx It also involves a command line param, but also shared memory, handle inheritance and security considerations :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is "No".

A more complex answer is "Not as easily as simply passing a command line param would be".

:)

What you need to do is identify the parent process of your process.  Obtaining this is possible but not straightforward.  Details of how to go about it can be obtained in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ParentPID.aspx).

The biggest problem is that there is not strict hierarchical relationship between processes in Windows and PID (Process ID's) may be re-used.  The PID you identify as your "parent" may not be your parent at all.  If the parent process has subsequently terminated then it's PID may be re-used which could lead to some seemingly perplexing results ("My process was started by calc.exe?  How is that possible?").

Trying to find bullet, water and idiot proof mechanisms to protect against the possible ways  such a process might fail will be significantly more effort than simply devising and implementing a command line based convention between your launcher applications and the launchee by which the latter may identify the former.

A command line parameter is one such option but could be "spoofed" (if someone figures out what you are passing on the command line and for some reason could derive some value or benefit from mimicking this themselves).

Depending on how reliable and tamper proof you need the mechanism to be, this could still be enough however.

Comment: The first sentence is the answer. The rest is an explanation of why that's true. (Which is exactly what I said that got a downvote.)

Comment: Yep, but I think I was reading the question and writing my answer at the same time you wrote yours (it wasn't posted when I added mine).  Myself, I like to explain why an answer is the way it is even if that is by way of exploding/debunking what might look like a potential contrary answer.  Otherwise it can lead to "Why not ?  I've seen XYZ other app do it / something similar" and supplementary explanation that must then follow.

Comment: Also sometimes it happens that explaining what I think to be the answer helps me come to a renewed understanding myself, occasionally realising that the answer I was about to give perhaps wasn't as cut and dried as I thought.  Not that you or everyone else has to follow that process, just explaining my own answering process.  :)

Comment: Agree. That's why I didn't downvote; just pointed out that it's not possible to **reliably** determine how your process was started. The best you can do is a "best guess". I'm not as quick to downvote as some people here - I can disagree without accusing people of being wrong. :)

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to do what you want, I'm afraid. The application isn't told whether it's being run pro grammatically via `ShellExecute` (or `CreateProcess`), via a command line, a shortcut, or a double-click in Explorer.

[Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing) did an article a while back on this very topic, if I remember correctly; I'll see if I can find it and update my answer here.

Comment: But perhaps you can obtain the PID of the parent process? Then you can analyse this and see if it corresponds to explorer.exe or myownapp.exe.

Comment: Explorer doesn't open it as a child process, according to Raymond. You also don't have to open it as a child when you just execute it via `ShellExecute` or `CreateProcess`, unless I'm mistaken. But I'm still trying to find the post I referenced. Did you downvote this answer? If so, why? I don't see any mention of why it's wrong.

Comment: I did. Because it completely misleading. 1. Get parent process then 2. get its image name (or whatever trait of interest)

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks. I didn't think so.

Comment: @Ken White, so you dont want any explanation next time when you will post "regardless" [mis]information?

Comment: @Ken White, before making any **demands** here you have to offer something for reasonable agreement.

Comment: @Ken White, you will be surprised how many posts of yours are wr... of mediocre quality. This one is definitely bad: written in hurry, misconception, no references. My critics is a favour, not the reason for loud BAWWWW. Ever heard about Narcissus and what happened to him, BTW? If you want code, then you want to decide how much you are willing to spend and approach with offer.

Comment: @Ken White, also you could cease bowing and conferring awards, and take little of your valuable time to provide a proper reference to Raymond Chen's statement on the subject. I'm suprised what someone decided to upvote this post...

Comment: No sense in degrading each other. Both of you want to help people, both do it voluntarily and both have the right to make mistakes. That's what the reviews are for, after all. If you really want to continue with your talk, why not creating a chat room?

Answer (score 5):

Based on another answer and some code on Torry.net, I came to this function to get the parent process id. It seems to return a relevant number on Windows 7, and the windows functions it uses should be available at least since Win 2000.

```
uses Tlhelp32;

function GetProcessInfo(ProcessId: Cardinal; out ParentProcessId: Cardinal; out ExeFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  hSnapShot: THandle;
  ProcInfo: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  hSnapShot := CreateToolHelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if (hSnapShot <> THandle(-1)) then
  try
    ProcInfo.dwSize := SizeOf(ProcInfo);

    if (Process32First(hSnapshot, ProcInfo)) then
      repeat
        if ProcInfo.th32ProcessID = ProcessId then
        begin
          ExeFileName := string(ProcInfo.szExeFile);
          ParentProcessId := ProcInfo.th32ParentProcessID;
          Result := True;
          Exit;
        end;
      until not Process32Next(hSnapShot, ProcInfo);
  finally
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
  end;

  Result := False;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  ProcessId, ParentProcessId, Dummy: Cardinal;
  FileName: string;
begin
  ProcessId := GetCurrentProcessId();
  // Get info for current process
  if GetProcessInfo(ProcessId, ParentProcessId, FileName) then
    // Get info for parent process
    if GetProcessInfo(ParentProcessId, Dummy, FileName) then
      // Show it.
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(ParentProcessId) + FileName);
end;
```

A word of caution! The parent process may no longer exist. Even worse, it's ID may have been recycled, causing this function to give you a different process than you asked for.

Comment: Since Win95, or maybe even Win32s (ToolHelp is very old)

Comment: "The big problem" is the reason I posted my answer as "No.". It's not reliable to use the PID for the reasons in your final paragraph.

Comment: @PrematureOptimization Yeah, I think it's old. There must be WinNT versions of this function too. But I run it on Windows 7 and it works. Also I can't find if it is deprecated. The name, however, suggests that this function may give you trouble in Win64. Anyway, just trying to make an effort.

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah, if used at all, you should run this function as soon as your program starts. This will give you the smallest risk of another process claiming the parent's process id. It seems quite usable for the purpose described by the OP.

Comment: I posted a slightly modified version of the function that returns the parent PID and the filename of a given process. By calling the function twice, you can get the exe name of the parent. For retrieving the full path, you will need to do some extra work, which is described in the MSDN documentation of [PROCESSENTRY32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @GolezTrol, exactly, PsAPI was favoured in the place of ToolHelp on NT, however it lacks "older" functionality. It is not deprecated and still in kernel. Also, despite of historical name, support 64bit with minor limitations.

Comment: Well, the code I based my function can be found [here](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=616). It has a WinNT equivalent too. Don't really know why I didn't use that in the first place. I guess it's getting late. :) It should be pretty easy to rebuild it using PsAPI.

Comment: @GolezTroi: The original question specifically said "a reliable way", which there isn't (as you've already mentioned in your answer). I'm not downvoting, but I can't upvote either. :)

Comment: Ah, out of curiousity i figured out why is it ToolHelp<b>32</b>. Because it is a continuation of ToolHelp of Windows 3.0 :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've found [getpids](http://www.scheibli.com/projects/getpids/) which does it using [NtQueryInformationProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to  not only to obtain the parent process ID but also compare the process creation times - if the reported parent process was created after the child it means the reported parent ID has already been recycled.

Here is my Delphi unit I wrote to test it:

```
unit ProcInfo;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

function GetParentProcessId(ProcessID: DWORD; out ProcessImageFileName: string): DWORD; overload;

implementation

uses
  PsApi;

var
  hNtDll: THandle;
  NtQueryInformationProcess: function(ProcessHandle: THandle; ProcessInformationClass: DWORD;
    ProcessInformation: Pointer; ProcessInformationLength: ULONG; ReturnLength: PULONG): DWORD; stdcall;

const
  UnicodeStringBufferLength = 1025;

type
  PPEB = Pointer; // PEB from winternl.h not needed here
  PPROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION = ^PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;
  PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION = record
    Reserved1: Pointer; // exit status
    PebBaseAddress: PPEB;
    Reserved2: array[0..1] of Pointer; // affinity mask, base priority
    UniqueProcessId: ULONG_PTR;
    Reserved3: Pointer; // parent process ID
  end;
  PProcessBasicInformation = ^TProcessBasicInformation;
  TProcessBasicInformation = PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;
  PKernelUserTimes = ^TKernelUserTimes;
  TKernelUserTimes = record
    CreateTime: LONGLONG;
    ExitTime: LONGLONG;
    KernelTime: LONGLONG;
    UserTime: LONGLONG;
  end;
  PUNICODE_STRING = ^UNICODE_STRING;
  UNICODE_STRING = record
    Length: USHORT;
    MaximumLength: USHORT;
    PBuffer: PChar;
    Buffer: array[0..UnicodeStringBufferLength - 1] of Char;
  end;
  PUnicodeString = ^TUnicodeString;
  TUnicodeString = UNICODE_STRING;

function GetProcessCreateTime(hProcess: THandle): LONGLONG;
var
  ProcessTimes: TKernelUserTimes;
begin
  Result := 0;
  FillChar(ProcessTimes, SizeOf(ProcessTimes), 0);
  if NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, 4, @ProcessTimes, SizeOf(ProcessTimes), nil) <> 0 then
    Exit;
  Result := ProcessTimes.CreateTime;
end;

function GetProcessParentId(hProcess: THandle): DWORD;
var
  ProcessInfo: TProcessBasicInformation;
begin
  Result := 0;
  FillChar(ProcessInfo, SizeOf(ProcessInfo), 0);
  if NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, 0, @ProcessInfo, SizeOf(ProcessInfo), nil) <> 0 then
    Exit;
  Result := DWORD(ProcessInfo.Reserved3);
end;

function GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess: THandle): string;
var
  ImageFileName: TUnicodeString;
begin
  Result := '';
  FillChar(ImageFileName, SizeOf(ImageFileName), 0);
  ImageFileName.Length := 0;
  ImageFileName.MaximumLength := UnicodeStringBufferLength * SizeOf(Char);
  ImageFileName.PBuffer := @ImageFileName.Buffer[0];

  if NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, 27, @ImageFileName, SizeOf(ImageFileName), nil) <> 0 then
    Exit;
  SetString(Result, ImageFileName.PBuffer, ImageFileName.Length);
end;

function GetParentProcessId(ProcessId: DWORD; out ProcessImageFileName: string): DWORD;
var
  hProcess, hParentProcess: THandle;
  ProcessCreated, ParentCreated: LONGLONG;
begin
  Result := 0;
  ProcessImageFileName := '';

  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, ProcessId);
  if hProcess = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    Result := GetProcessParentId(hProcess);
    if Result = 0 then
      Exit;
    ProcessCreated := GetProcessCreateTime(hProcess);
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
  end;

  hParentProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, Result);
  if hParentProcess = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    ParentCreated := GetProcessCreateTime(hParentProcess);
    if ParentCreated > ProcessCreated then
    begin
      Result := 0;
      Exit;
    end;

    ProcessImageFileName := GetProcessImageFileName(hParentProcess);
  finally
    CloseHandle(hParentProcess);
  end;
end;

initialization
  hNtDll := GetModuleHandle('ntdll.dll');
  if hNtDll <> 0 then
    NTQueryInformationProcess := GetProcAddress(hNtDll, 'NtQueryInformationProcess');

end.
```

When I run the code from the IDE, I get the following results:

> parent ID: 5140, parent image file name:
>   "\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD
>   Studio\8.0\bin\bds.exe"

so you may need to find a way to translate that into a "normal" path, e.g. "C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin\bds.exe".

Comment: Scratch RaiseLastOSError, NtXXX will not set `errno`, so message ought to be unrelated with actual error occured. Proper error message could be retrieved by passing NTSTATUS return value to `FormatMessage`